# String Manipulation with sprintf and char* in vugen

Tags: c, loadrunner

I am working with Loadrunner vugen,
 I have a web_custom_request which produces a huge XML with the following format

```
//name of the code
      [
         {share-value: 24
         share - time ; 3
         share kind : x
         share number : 10
         share owneere : Vijay
        ....}
         {share-value: 24
         share - time ; 3
         share kind : x
         share number : 10
         share owneere : Vijay
        ....}
        {share-value: 24
         share - time ; 3
         share kind : x
         share number : 10
         share owneere : Vijay
        ....}
    ]
```

This needs to be manipulated in the following format and put as input to the next request.

```
      {Original request"/{[[
         {"//share-value: "//24
         //share - time ; "//3
         share kind : "//x
         share number : "//10
         share owneere : "//Vijay
         -- additional attributes added like 
         share price vlues :"// Y
         share checked     : "//Y
        ....}
       '
       .}
       Changed respose 
       /{[[
         {"//share-value: "//24
         //share - time ; "//3
         share kind : "//x
         share number : "//10
         share owneere : "//Vijay
         -- additional attributes added like 
         share price vlues :"// Y
         share checked     : "//Y
        ....}
```

Can any one suggest any easy methods to do it.   I am using the string manipulations but im getting a lot of issues with strcat and sprintf functions. Primarily because sprintf does not really work well with char*

```
     sprintf(new_string,"original response",existing_response)
```

getting memory violation exception. as Char* is giving issues.   Char Array is solving the issue but the size of the array needs to be close to 10000, i am declaring like

```
    char new_string[10000];
```

Comment: Your question is not particularly related to LoadRunner but more to C coding. Have you considered changing the programming language to JavaScript or use the TruWeb protocol?

Comment: "sprintf does not really work well with char*" you need to allocate memory and assign the address of the allocated memory to the char*. Also remember to `free()` it once it's no longer needed.